# Spring - Make microservice only accessible internally

Tags: spring, spring-security, microservices

How can I setup a microservice which can only be called by other internal services. The microservice should not be accessible in public, because it has access to databases with secret information. I already tried to secure the microservice with spring security but in this case I got problems with the FeignClient concerning authorization.

Comment: Your microservice and all the databases it talks to should be behind firewalls.  I would not rely only on Spring Security.

Comment: So at the end the only thing which is not behind the firewall will be the api gateway ? Thanks for your answer

Comment: I would have a gateway that would authenticate and re-direct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are unable to solve this problem with infrastructure
(which is the only correct way to solve this problem),
there are several (bad) techniques you can use:

1. IP Address White List - Create a list of good IP Addresses, reject any request from an address not on the list.
2. IP Address Zone - Variation of the white list.  Create a list of partial IP Addresses and reject any request that does not match one of the partial addresses.
3. Non-Routing IP Only - Variation of IP Address Zone.  Only accept requests from non-routing IP addresses only (these can only be on your local network).  Here is a [Wiki page of non-routing IP addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses)
4. Magic token.  Only accept requests that include a specific token.  This is especially terrible, because somebody can watch your traffic and discover the token.

There are probably other options, but go with Infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

This is really an infrastructure question. Typically you want to have a private network with all your resources internally - the so called [De-Militarized-Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)) or DMZ - and then have a second network or endpoint bridge that provides external access. The internal network should not be reachable from the internet. The endpoint could be a single server or an array of servers that are implemented as a [bastion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host) host and will authenticate and authorize callers and forward calls to the private network that are legitimate.

The API gateway (or edge-server) pattern is often used to realize this. A good configuration of the gateway is important.

Here is an [article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html) of how to do it with the Amazon cloud.

And here a [link](https://getkong.org/) to Kong, a general API gateway that you can deploy yourself.